# asp-classic to .NET conversion... i could use some suggestions

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, asp-classic

i'm converting a classic asp website to .NET and could use some suggestions to this problem.

original code:

```
Dim oCountCMD
oCountCMD = Server.CreateObject("ADODB.Command")
With oCountCMD
    .ActiveConnection = Application("ConnString")
    .CommandText = "sp_GetSearchHistoryCount"
    .CommandType = .CommandType.StoredProcedure
    .oCountCMD(1) = strUser
    .oCountCMD(2) = DateAdd("n", -1, Now())
    .Execute()

    If oCountCMD(0) > 60 Then
        CheckSearchCounts = True
    Else
        CheckSearchCounts = False
    End If
End With
oCountCMD = Nothing
```

my unfinished converted code:

```
Dim objConnection As New SqlConnection(Application("ConnString"))
Dim oCountCMD As New SqlCommand("sp_GetSearchHistoryCount", objConnection)

With oCountCMD
    .CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure

    .Parameters.Add(New SqlParameter("@UserName", SqlDbType.VarChar, 20))
    .Parameters("@UserName").Value = strUser

    .Parameters.Add(New SqlParameter("@SearchDt", SqlDbType.DateTime))
    .Parameters("@SearchDt").Value = DateAdd("n", -1, Now())

    // need to execute here, and find number of rows/records returned
End With
```

how can i capture the number of rows returned when i execute this stored procedure?

Comment: Whats the stored proc signature? Do you have any out parameters?

Comment: the signature is "sp_GetSearchHistoryCount", and i don't know what an out parameter is. this stored proc takes only two parameters, @UserName and @SearchDt.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try

```
Dim theCount Integer 
theCount = .ExecuteScalar()
```

Answer (score 1):

Thanks for the comment update.

If the response of the Stored proc is a single value then you need to execute the SqlCommand which you have setup. If you `ExecuteScaler()` on this command then it will return an single Sql type, most likely and int and then you can convert it into a .net value.

Hope it helps :-)

Answer (score 1):

```
Dim countEffected As Integer=0

With oCountCMD
    .CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure    
    .Parameters.Add(New SqlParameter("@UserName", SqlDbType.VarChar, 20, strUser))       
    .Parameters.Add(New SqlParameter("@SearchDt", SqlDbType.DateTime,,DateAdd("n", -1, Now())))

    countEffected = .ExecuteScalar()    
End With

'return true/false as previous VB6 did.
CheckSearchCounts = countEffected > 60
```